# Most efficient way to stream video in Electron application? (getUserMedia?)

Tags: javascript, electron, html5-video, webcam, getusermedia

For example, suppose I have

```html
<video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
```

and then I start streaming video:

```js
async function startVideo() {
    const video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
    const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
    video.srcObject = mediaStream
}

startVideo()
```

Will the underlying implementation in on the native side of the browser be using some zero-copy approach to get the video onto the screen?

If not, what may be the most efficient way to get the camera onto the screen if I'm in an Electron app?

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium browser implementation in Electron is generally at parity with browser versions. Therefore, it should handle the display of the incoming video camera data efficiently.